# How to update field after ubercart checkout completion?

Tags: 7, rules, ubercart

I have created a field (checkbox) in user profile edit form that is only visible to admin.

When the user completed their checkout process (after payment) that field which I created previously must be updated (I.e: checked).

I want to implement this functionality for letting admin know about who has purchased the subscription plan .

How could I do it by using rule or something else?

Comment: I have to do it with Drupal 7

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [Rules module](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) for the after checkout event then use some custom php code to update your field.

you might need to add [Commerce Rules Extra module](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_rules_extra) to get the checkout event in rules.